# Sql request without same values

Tags: mysql, sql, request

Task:
output count of rows where `status=0` and their `topic` column's value is not the same.

Request:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),topic FROM requests WHERE status=0 GROUP BY topic
```

Table:

```
id|userid|title|text|topic|status
---------------------------------
1 | 0001 | one |abcd|  1  |  0
2 | 0002 | ans |abcd|  1  |  0
```

**Problem:** it returns 2 instead of 1 (because those rows has the same value in topic column).

Comment: "topic column's value is not the same."  Not the same as what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want the number of distinct topics where `status = 0`:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct topic)
FROM requests
WHERE status = 0;
```